# complexity for recursion function

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have written a function for reverse a stack inline. these two are member function of stack class .

```
void reverse()
{
    int first=pop();
    if(first!=-1)
    {
        reverse();
        insert(first);
    }
}
private:
void insert(int i)
{
    int temp=pop();

    if(temp==-1)
    {
       push(i);     
    }
    else
    { 
       /* there is already a element in the stack*/
       insert(i);
       push(temp);

    }
}
```

Now how can i analyze my function in form of big O to calculate complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Your `insert()` takes `O(length of the stack)` time because:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)[to push] = O(n)
```

and your `reverse()` takes `O(square of the length of the stack)` time because:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)[for insert] = O(n^2)
```